# Android unable to launch the app in emulator

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-studio

I am newbie in mobile app development. I am working on `android studio`. I have created two tables in `mysql DB`, one of them is `users` and the other one is `activity`. For now i am working with the `users` table. My task is to make an `app` in which there should be a `dropdown` and all the user names will be in it. When a user selects any of the name the `id` of that user will be shown.

For this i created a `php` file in which i have returned a `json` result.

Below is my `php` code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";


$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
   array_push($result,array(
    'Id'=>$row['Id'],
    'Name'=>$row['Name']
   ));
}

  echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

  mysqli_close($con);
```

Below is the result of the above code

```
{"users":[{"Id":"1","Name":"Faisal"},{"Id":"2","Name":"Salman"},{"Id":"3","Name":"Asim"},{"Id":"4","Name":"Asad"},{"Id":"5","Name":"Mateen"}]}
```

Now shifting towards my android part

Below is my `Config file`

```
public class Config {

//JSON URL
public static final String DATA_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/MobileApp/index.php";

//Tags used in the JSON String

public static final String TAG_NAME = "Name";

public static final String TAG_ID = "Id";

//JSON array name
public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "users";

}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener {

  //Declaring an Spinner
 private Spinner spinner;

//An ArrayList for Spinner Items
private ArrayList<String> users;

//JSON Array
private JSONArray result;

//TextViews to display details
private TextView textViewResult;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //Initializing the ArrayList
    users = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Initializing Spinner
    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);


    //Adding an Item Selected Listener to our Spinner
    //As we have implemented the class Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener to this class iteself
    // we are passing this to setOnItemSelectedListener

    spinner.setOnItemClickListener((AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) this);

    //Initializing TextView

    textViewResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    //This method will fetch the data from the URL
    getData();
}

private void getData() {

    //Creating a string request
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Config.DATA_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JSONObject j = null;
                    try {
                        //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                        j = new JSONObject(response);

                        //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                        result = j.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);

                        //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                        getUsers(result);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    //Creating a request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void getUsers(JSONArray j) {

    //Traversing through all the items in the json array
    for(int i =0; i<j.length(); i++)
    {
        try
        {
            //Getting json object
            JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);

            //Adding the name of the student to array list
            users.add(json.getString(Config.TAG_NAME));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

 //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner

    spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, users));
}

private void getUsers() {


}

//Method to get student name of a particular position
private String getName(int position)
{
    String name = "";
    try
    {
        //Getting object of given index
        JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);
        //Fetching name from that object
        name = json.getString(Config.TAG_NAME);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return name;
}

//Method to get student Id of a particular position
private String getId (int postion)
{
    String Id="";
    try{
        JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(postion);

        Id = json.getString(Config.TAG_ID);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Id;
}

//this method will execute when we pic an item from the spinner
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    //Appending the values to textview for a selected item

    textViewResult.append("Hi " + getName(position) + "Your ID is " + getId(position));
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    textViewResult.setText("");

}}
```

For now i am running the app in the emulator using `10.0.2.2`. When i run the app the app crashes and at `logcat` i get the following error

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.accurat.webaccess/com.example.accurat.webaccess.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.accurat.webaccess.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemClickListener
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.accurat.webaccess.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemClickListener
                                                                             at com.example.accurat.webaccess.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:64)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

And it hits at `textViewResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);`

**Update 1**

By using `spinner.setOnItemClickListener(this);` i am getting below error

[image]

I know there are many questions on it i have looked into them but still i am unable to solve the issue.

I have no idea what is the problem. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This line is your error: `spinner.setOnItemClickListener((AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) this);`. 'this' (your MainActivity) does not implement AdapterView.OnItemClickListener

Comment: use :`spinner.setOnItemClickListener(this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
```

Now:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener
```

And in your activity:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)
```

You have to overWrite the following method also:

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    //write your code
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try importing `android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;`
This is a common problem in eclipse as mentioned in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8888996/5803493)

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to do with android studio.

> **Step 1**: put cursor on red line word (here it is 'this')
>
> **Step 2**: press Alt+Enter key
>
> **Step 3**: Select Make OnItemSelectedListener
>
> **Step 4**: press ok button on your next dialogue box..done.

Usually this kind of questions can be googled.

First we have to look on the log.
Second we have to find what is the problem is.

In your log you can see **Caused by** tag followed by exception.

here its `ClassCastException` on line 64.

Just google it that exception. cheers